# Spinner returning null value

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, spinner, android-spinner

[Spinner shows list, but on selection shows blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRC9b.png)
I have been working with Spinners for a while now. Everything was working fine. But for last few days I am facing a rather peculiar problem with spinners. I had created a spinner in xml and passed a dynamic list to it(fetched from a webservice). After repeatedly getting null pointer, i tried creating the spinner dynamically. Here is the code:

```
 vendorSpinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams vsParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
        vendorSpinner.setLayoutParams(vsParams);
        init(); //To call the webservice and get the list
        currentVendor=vendorSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        try {
            vendorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    if (currentVendor!=i){
                        VendorData vd = (VendorData) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                        vendorName.setText(vd.getName());
                    }
                    currentVendor=i;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in Spinner::::::::::"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        vendorLayout.addView(vendorSpinner);
```

The spinner loads the list, but when an item is selected, the value is null and the textView doesnt get the text. Please help!!

Comment: if (currentVendor!=i){  what is this ?

Comment: @HaseebMirza this is for not selecting 1st item by default.

Comment: Could you show me 'init' method?

Comment: ```
        getVendorData();
        ArrayAdapter<VendorData> vendorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, vendorList);
        vendorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        vendorSpinner.setAdapter(vendorAdapter); ``` @Genesis